# Difference between Fourier transform of $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-k}$ with $k\le -1$ and $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k}$ with $k\ge 1$

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform

When I want to calculate the discrete Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{3}^{-k}$ with $k\le-1$ I get that:
$$
\sum_{k=-{\infty}}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-k}e^{-j\omega k} = \sum_{k'=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}e^{j\omega}\right)^{k'} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}e^{j\omega}}{1-\frac{1}{3}e^{j\omega}}
$$
But if I change the variable before finding the Fourier transform I have the function $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k$ with $k\ge1$ (both functions are the same). The discrete Fourier transform of the new function is as follows:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k}e^{-j\omega k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}e^{-j\omega}\right)^{k} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}e^{-j\omega}}{1-\frac{1}{3}e^{-j\omega}}
$$
Are these two the same?

Comment: The sequence $\{(1/3)^{-k}\}$ for $k\leq -1$ is not the same sequence as $\{(1/3)^{m}\}$ for $m \geq 1$.

Comment: @AtulIngle you mean the order of the sequence? but the results of them in a definite point are equal, why is the order important?

Comment: See plots here. http://imgur.com/a/gVXpI The two sequences are mirror images in time i.e. flipped. This explains why their DFTs has a sign change on the frequency variable.

Comment: @AtulIngle Oh you're right, I got it, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Atul has pointed out, your both sequences are not the same, but they are time-reversed versions of each other:

```
k = np.arange(-15, 15)

s1 = (1/3.)**(-k)*(k <= -1);
s2 = (1/3.)**(+k)*(k >= +1)


plt.stem(k, s1, 'r')
plt.stem(k, s2, 'g')
```

[image: program output]

Accordingly, what you see in your calculations is the [time-reversal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-Time_Fourier_transform#Properties) of the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform:

$$x(t)=y(-t) \Leftrightarrow X(f)=Y(-f)$$

I.e. the frequency changes its sign in your calculations, as is expected from the time-reversal property.

Comment: To nitpick here, we can say by the time-reversal property of the DTFT :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Properties

Comment: right :-) I just edited it.